# Android Store Content URI or Filesystem Path for Media

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-mediaplayer, android-contentresolver

I have an application where I allow users to chose a media file to use as an alert. I query the `MediaStore` like this:

```
String[] projec = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, 
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};

Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver()
                        .query(internalOrExternal, projec, null, null, null);
```

where `internalOrExternal` is a parameter that is either `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` or `MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.

I use the value from the `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` column if it starts with `content://`, otherwise I call `MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(c.getString(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA))` and if the result from that begins with `content://` I use that value.

When I load the data structure that holds the URI for the media, I check the URI against the `MediaStore` to make sure that it still exists, and if it doesn't I set it to a default alert (guaranteed to exist).

Recently, I've had users (all with Samsung devices) complaining that every few weeks all of their alerts are set to use the default alert even though they set them to use custom ones (in one user's case, over 40 alerts reverted back to the default). They assure me that they did not clear data, or do anything that would have impacted the app's storage (one informed me that this happened after updating to Android 4.3).

Is it possible that certain vendors reassign their content URIs? Should I be storing the content URIs or the filesystem path and resolve it to a content URI when I want to play the alert?

Answer (score 0):

I think the MediaStore only encapsulates Media Files it has access to and is not the original provider, just a middle man. I believe anytime a user's phone updates, the phone's filesystem gets re-indexed and that might be causing the issue for updates.